# PHP array loop by link and same name

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I can not understand. Why this code remove last item. But if i change $item in second loop on $item2, or use link, it work fine.

```
<?php
$list = [
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
    ['id' => 3],
    ['id' => 4],
    ['id' => 5],
    ['id' => 6],
];

$selected = [2,3,4,6];
$hidden = [4,5];

foreach ($list as &$item) {
    if(in_array($item['id'], $selected)) {
        $item['selected'] = true;
    }
}

foreach ($list as $key=>$item) {
    if(in_array($item['id'], $hidden)) {
        unset($list[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($list);
```

Comment: use `unset($item)` after the first `foreach` to break the association of `$item` with the last array element

Comment: why, in first foreach  you are accessinng to &$item   ... ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) states:

> Warning: Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even
>   after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

so something like this should work:

```
foreach ($list as &$item) {
    //do some stuff
}
unset($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

`unset()` the hidded keys first and then check for selected id's

```
foreach ($list as $key => $item) {
    if(in_array($item['id'],$hidden)){
        unset($list[$key]);
    } 
}

foreach ($list as &$item) {
    if(in_array($item['id'], $selected)) {
        $item['selected'] = true;
    }
}
```